# Anchor build says "cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer" but I have a newer rustc installed

Tags: anchor, rustc

When I run `anchor build` or `anchor test`:

```
error: package `solana-program v1.16.3` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev.
```

But checking `rustc` returns:

```
% rustc --version
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

How can I fix the error? Why is anchor not using the `rustc` I have installed?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue bc I had done `rustup update` but didn't follow up with `rustup default <version number>` and so it hadn't actually switched over.

What do you get when you run `rustc --version`?

Comment: rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)

Comment: Be sure to update your Solana build tools by running `solana-install init 1.16.3`

Comment: Similar problem here. ----------
error: package `toml_edit v0.21.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.69 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.69 or newer, or use
cargo update -p toml_edit@0.21.1 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `toml_edit` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev ----------
How can I fix the error? I'm using anchor 0.29.0, solana-cli 1.17.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this same issue with `solana-program v1.16.5` and `rustc 1.71.0 (8ede3aae2 2023-07-12)`.

No idea what the correct way to resolve this would be but downgrading to `solana-program v1.16.3` worked for me.

So basically only thing I did is instead of running `solana-install update` which updates to the latest stable version I just ran `solana-install init 1.16.3` and things started to work.

Comment: This answer works but the other one - where you update your Solana Tools instead of downgrading - is better.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `anchor build`, or `cargo build-sbf` or `cargo build-bpf` (which is deprecated) [it uses rustc installed with Solana tools](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34987#issuecomment-1914675549). To check the version of `rustc` from Solana Tools, runs:

```
cargo-build-sbf --version
```

To fix the error you need to get latest (or newer enough for your program dependencies) Solana tools. Run the following command to upgrade your Solana tools:

```
$ solana-install init 1.16.15
```

*You may want to replace "1.16.15" with the [latest available version](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases) or required version (see your error message).*

Comment: read in details and up to date explanation and solution https://dmitryshvetsov.com/shorts/how-to-fix-solana-program-cannot-be-build-requires-newer-rustc/

Answer (score 3):

use `rustup` to select the correct version - to compile onto solana correctly you need to match the runtime of the target environment (devnet,testnet,mainnet-beta)

A lot of Solana rust deps are also locked to 1.62.3 - if you upgrade past this then you will get module based issues

To fix mod issues add this constraint to Anchor.toml `solana-program = "=1.14.20"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I checked `cargo-build-sbf --version` it seemed to be older versions.
I got result 
*solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.25

platform-tools v1.37

rustc 1.68.0*
After I used `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.18.8/install)"` to update to Solana version 1.18.8 I ran `cargo-build-sbf --version` again
with result
*solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.8

platform-tools v1.41*
RustC was not mentioned anymore.
I installed the Rust installer again by using

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

After this the `anchor test` command ran without any errors
 
I hope this works for you too...