# Unable to build a binary

Tags: cargo, build-bpf, rustc, build-sbf

Both `anchor build` and `cargo-build-sbf` throw:

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/usr1/solana/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
error: package `solana-program v1.16.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

`cargo build` actually works, but it does not produce deploy directory.

But apparently I do have the rust version:

```
rustc -V
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
cargo-build-sbf
error: package `solana-program v1.16.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

Other versions:

```
cargo build-sbf -V
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.12.0
sbf-tools v1.29

cargo --version
cargo 1.69.0 (6e9a83356 2023-04-12)
```

Same results for setting with `rustup default 1.69.0`.

I've updated solana, rustc and pretty much everything else. It always breaks on this.

My `anchor.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "proj"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "proj"
ls

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.28.0"
anchor-spl = "0.28.0"
solana-program = "=1.16.4"
switchboard-v2 = "0.4.0"
bytemuck = "1.13.1"
```

This [issue](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/solana-building-error-for-v1-16-3-it-says-i-have-rustc-v-1-62-0-dev-but-my-c) suggests following constraint to Anchor.toml `solana-program = "=1.14.20"`, this won't work with `switchboard-v2 = "^0.4.0"`.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try updating to the latest `solana-cli` suite using

```
solana-install init 1.16.4
```

Also, the error has nothing with your `rustc` version, but the crates' MSRV.

Answer (score 2):

Hey the error that you are using and old rust version comes from you having cli 14.x installed probably. Can you try updating it to 16.4? https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: I just tried building with your dependencies and its seems to work just. What does solana --version say and whats the error your are getting?

Comment: solana-cli 1.16.4 (src:4ce8fe76; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)

Comment: And what error are you getting? For me its building fine. Maybe try deleting the cargo.lock file and build again with anchor build

Answer (score 0):

After running `anchor build` I got this:

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/usr1/solana/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
error: package `solana-program v1.16.5` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

I followed to `/Users/usr1/solana` nuked the `/bin` directory, run `anchor build` again and this time it rebuild everything and I guess from now would use global rustc rather than the one that was under `/Users/usr1/solana`.