# Anchor compatibility issues

Tags: anchor, rust, cli, rustc

Whenever I try to run `anchor build`, I am greeted with a package incompatibility error, saying that my rustc toolchain version is too low (1.62.0-dev) but my toolchain is set to 1.75.0.
Here's the error:
`` error: package `solana-program v1.17.14` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev ``

Comment: Hey Morgan, you are getting this error either because your Solana cli is outdated, or you need to cargo add solana-program@=1.17.3.

Answer (score 4):

If rustup update doesn’t work it’s probably the fact that Solana has a different rustc version set in the tool chain.

Check this post or like a dozen similar ones.

[solana building error for v1.16.3. it says I have rustc --v 1.62.0-dev. but my current rustc version is rustc 1.70.0](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/solana-building-error-for-v1-16-3-it-says-i-have-rustc-v-1-62-0-dev-but-my-c)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to update to the newest solana version 1.17 like so:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.17.17/install)"
```

https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

and also use anchor 29 which you can define in the Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
```

Here are the anchor docs:
https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/installation

In case you want to do smth wiht token2022 also update the SPL token version
there:

```
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
solana-program = "1.17.17"
```

Answer (score 2):

I Found the answer, turns out you *also* need to make changes to your solana install.
I used `solana-install init 1.17.14`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error while building Anchor project. anchor build
But it was built successfully.
I'm not sure if it's because of version compatibility.

`Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17h2f3c0d426ad8ac9bE Stack offset of 4584 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 488 bytes, please minimize large stack variables`

solana-cli 1.18.1
anchor 0.29.0
rustc 1.76.0

Anyone could help me? Thanks

Comment: Hey there Julbh  so sometimes accounts are too large and violate the current stack limits set by solana. Box may be able to help since it allocates to the heap.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you can see, the error instruction is in solana_program, not in my custom program. So I think it's because of compatibility issue.

Please take a look. The same error.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/35003

But it didn't fix my problem.