# error: package `solana-program v1.18.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, error, rustc, version

I tried setting up an Anchor project on my MacBook with an ARM processor, but I encountered an error. Here is step by step that i took

```
% anchor init testproject
Only x86_64 / Linux distributed in NPM package right now.
Trying globally installed anchor.
yarn install v1.22.19
...
testproject initialized
% cd testproject 
% anchor build
Only x86_64 / Linux distributed in NPM package right now.
Trying globally installed anchor.
error: package `solana-program v1.18.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.72.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.1 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
```

Here is all installed version

```
% rustup -V
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`

% rustc -V
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)

% cargo -V 
cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)

% solana -V
solana-cli 1.16.3 (src:bc7870f3; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)

% anchor -V
Only x86_64 / Linux distributed in NPM package right now.
Trying globally installed anchor.
anchor-cli 0.29.0
```

I've tried to init 1.16.3 version for solana-install this [post](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/solana-building-error-for-v1-16-3-it-says-i-have-rustc-v-1-62-0-dev-but-my-c) but it doesn't work for me.
I also tried to manually update a dependency (toml_edit) to a specific version hoping it would fix the problem, but it wasn't.

```
cargo update -p toml_edit@0.21.1  --precise 0.21.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue for a new program I created. However the older program which I created a couple of days back still works fine. I referred to [solana building error for v1.16.3. it says I have rustc --v 1.62.0-dev. but my current rustc version is rustc 1.70.0](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/solana-building-error-for-v1-16-3-it-says-i-have-rustc-v-1-62-0-dev-but-my-c) and ran the below command to fix it:

```
solana-install init 1.18.1
```

Comment: it is working with 1.18.1. many thanks

Comment: This solved this similar error as well. Thanks!
`error: package toml_edit v0.21.1 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.69 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev`

Comment: Literally the only answer to these "old `rustc`" problems is to upgrade the version of cargo-builf-bfp: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34987#issuecomment-1914675549