# anchor-error: How to fix the error : "package `toml_edit v0.21.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.69 or newer" on Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program

While building anchor project, I faced the follow error:

`` "error: package `toml_edit v0.21.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.69 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev Either upgrade to rustc 1.69 or newer, or use cargo update -p toml_edit@0.21.1 --precise ver where `ver` is the latest version of `toml_edit` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev" ``

My current project is:
`rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`
`anchor-cli 0.28.0`
`solana-cli 1.16.13`

I tried `solana-install init 1.16.13`. But it didnt help me.

I am not sure what the reason and solution of this error.

My OS is ubuntu 22.04.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
solana-install init 1.18.1
```

You may also need to upgrade to anchor 0.29.

Similar issue the 1.18.1 fixed [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9930/error-package-solana-program-v1-18-1-cannot-be-built-because-it-requires-rust/9982#comment8105_9982).